# How to handle dynamic html tables in page object model using page fatory in selenium?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, pageobjects

I have an HTML page and created the page objects of that page. This page contains a dynamic html table. I'm unable to use it as page objects as it is dynamically created. I want to use any row and column of the page in my test cases.

Page Object class:

```
public final class AgentsPage 
{
@FindBy(how=How.XPATH, using="//table[@id='gwt-debug-com.seamless.ers.client.agentPortal.client.view.screens.SubAgentsReportScreen']//input[@id='gwt-debug-Phone_Number']")
public WebElement phoneNumber;

public String getTextOfPhoneNumber()
{
    return phoneNumber.getAttribute("value");
}

public void setTextForPhoneNumber(String value)
{
    phoneNumber.clear();
    phoneNumber.sendKeys(value);
}

@FindBy(how=How.XPATH, using="//table[@id='gwt-debug-com.seamless.ers.client.agentPortal.client.view.screens.SubAgentsReportScreen']//input[@id='gwt-debug-Name']")
public WebElement name;

public String getTextOfName()
{
    return name.getAttribute("value");
}

public void setTextForName(String value)
{
    name.clear();
    name.sendKeys(value);
}

@FindBy(how=How.XPATH, using="//table[@id='gwt-debug-com.seamless.ers.client.agentPortal.client.view.screens.SubAgentsReportScreen']//input[@id='gwt-debug-Reseller_ID']")
public WebElement resellerId;

public String getTextOfResellerId()
{
    return resellerId.getAttribute("value");
}

public void setTextForResellerId(String value)
{
    resellerId.clear();
    resellerId.sendKeys(value);
}

@FindBy(how=How.XPATH, using="//table[@id='gwt-debug-com.seamless.ers.client.agentPortal.client.view.screens.SubAgentsReportScreen']//input[@id='gwt-debug-Terminal_Serial']")
public WebElement terminalSerial;

public String getTextOfTermialSerial()
{
    return terminalSerial.getAttribute("value");
}

public void setTextForTerminalSerial(String value)
{
    terminalSerial.clear();
    terminalSerial.sendKeys(value);
}

@FindBy(how=How.XPATH, using="//table[@id='gwt-debug-com.seamless.ers.client.agentPortal.client.view.screens.SubAgentsReportScreen']//select[@id='gwt-debug-Rows_Per_Page']")
public WebElement rowsPerPage;

public String getSelectedValueOfRowsPerPage()
{
    Select select=new Select(rowsPerPage);
    return select.getFirstSelectedOption().getText();
}

public void setValueForRowsPerPage(String visibleText)
{
    if(!(visibleText.equals("")||visibleText==null))
    {
        Select select=new Select(rowsPerPage);
        select.selectByVisibleText(visibleText);
    }
}

public void setValueForRowsPerPage(int index) throws Exception
{
    Select select=new Select(resellerId);
    select.selectByIndex(index);
}

@FindBy(how=How.XPATH, using="//table[@id='gwt-debug-com.seamless.ers.client.agentPortal.client.view.screens.SubAgentsReportScreen']//button[@id='gwt-debug-submit_button']")
public WebElement submit;

public String getTextOfSubmit()
{
    return submit.getText();
}

@FindBy(how=How.XPATH, using="//table[@id='gwt-debug-com.seamless.ers.client.agentPortal.client.view.screens.SubAgentsReportScreen']//button[@id='gwt-debug-clear_button']")
public WebElement reset;

public String getTextOfReset()
{
    return reset.getText();
}

@FindBy(how=How.XPATH, using="//table[@id='gwt-debug-com.seamless.ers.client.agentPortal.client.view.screens.SubAgentsReportScreen']//button[@id='gwt-debug-nextPage']")
public WebElement next;

public String getTextOfNext()
{
    return next.getText();
}

@FindBy(how=How.XPATH, using="//table[@id='gwt-debug-com.seamless.ers.client.agentPortal.client.view.screens.SubAgentsReportScreen']//button[@id='gwt-debug-prevPage']")
public WebElement previous;

public String getTextOfPrevious()
{
    return previous.getText();
}

@FindBy(how=How.XPATH, using="//table[@id='gwt-debug-com.seamless.ers.client.agentPortal.client.view.screens.SubAgentsReportScreen']//button[@id='gwt-debug-lastPage']")
public WebElement last;

public String getTextOfLast()
{
    return last.getText();
}

@FindBy(how=How.XPATH, using="//table[@id='gwt-debug-com.seamless.ers.client.agentPortal.client.view.screens.SubAgentsReportScreen']//button[@id='gwt-debug-firstPage']")
public WebElement first;

public String getTextOfFirst()
{
    return first.getText();
}

@FindBy(how=How.XPATH, using="//table[@id='gwt-debug- com.seamless.ers.client.agentPortal.client.view.screens.SubAgentsReportScreen']//div[contains(text(),'Page:') and contains(text(),'/')]")
public WebElement pageCount;

public String getTextOfPageCount()
{
    return pageCount.getText();
}
//Need page objects for the dynamic html table
}
```

![Page Image][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/o94F0.png

I don't want to use any xpath or any loops for iterating through rows of the table in my test cases. I just want to use it like any other static page object elements like AgentsPage.submit button. How can this be achieved?

Comment: **Moderator Note**: Please do not vandalize your posts. Once you post a question, they belong to the site and its users. Even if it is no longer useful to you, it might be helpful to someone in the future. The answerers would have also put an effort in writing their answer, which would no longer be useful if you have removed the content from the post. Also, note that by posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the CC BY-SA 3.0 license). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Comment: I understand this case. But those code were mistakenly taken from my organisation and I was told to take it down as it was a pure violation. However those codes were not that helpful as the question describes the problem. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well without xPath you won't even locate needed elements of the table (well you may use CssSelectors but it's the same).

Do do it right I suggest you to create a list of web elements that will include table rows (`<tr>` tags). This list should be initialized by `@FindBy` attribute.

Then I suppose it's good idea to create "get" methods for your data.

**For example:**

```
public String getName(int row, int cell)
{
    return theTable[row].findElement(By.xpath(".//td[" + cell + "]")).getText();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Store the webelements like row number, phone number, name, etc etc in a list of its own. You can easily get the data as string using streams.

```
@FindBy(xpath="xpath to the row number")
private List<WebElement> rowNum;

@FindBy(xpath="xpath to the phone number")
private List<WebElement> phoneNum;
```

Similarly for other two. The data will be in order as found on the page. You can easily access data using index on the list.